# parse data from Dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, string, parsing, dictionary

So i have this dictionary "runs":

```
[{
'id': 12,
'suite_id': 2,
'name': 'name',
'description': "desc.",
'nice_id': 3,
'joku_id': None,
'onko': False,
'eikai': False,
'tehty': None,
'config': None,
'config_ids': [],
'passed_count': 1,
'blocked_count': 2,
'untested_count': 3,
'retest_count': 4,
'failed_count': 5,
'custom_status1_count': 0,
'custom_status2_count': 0,
'custom_status3_count': 0,
'custom_status4_count': 0,
'custom_status5_count': 0,
'custom_status6_count': 0,
'custom_status7_count': 0,
'projekti_id': 1,
'plan_id': None,
'created_on': 12343214,
'created_by': 11,
'url': 'google.com'
}, {
'id': 16,
'suite_id': 2,
'name': 'namae)',
'description': "desc1",
'nice_id': 5,
'joku_id': None,
'onko': False,
'eikai': False,
'tehty': None,
'config': None,
'config_ids': [],
'passed_count': 100,
'blocked_count': 1,
'untested_count': 3,
'retest_count': 2,
'failed_count': 5,
'custom_status1_count': 0,
'custom_status2_count': 0,
'custom_status3_count': 0,
'custom_status4_count': 0,
'custom_status5_count': 0,
'custom_status6_count': 0,
'custom_status7_count': 0,
'prokti_id': 7,
'plan_id': None,
'created_on': 4321341644,
'created_by': 11,
'url': 'google.com/2' }
```

there is "id" for about 50 times. that is just a part of it.
i need to find all "id":s (Not joku_ids, ncie_ids etc. Only "id") and make  a string/dict of them
and same for name, and description

i have tried:

```
j = json.load(run)
ids = (j["id"])

j = json.load(run)
names = (j["name"])

j = json.load(run)
descriptions = (j["description"])
```

but it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I also need to send a request with specific id and in this case the specific id is marked by o. so id[o]
the request code is below:

```
test = client.send_get('get_tests/1/ ')
```

so i need to have the id[o] instead of the 1.
i have tried

```
test = client.send_get('get_tests/' + id[o] + '/ ')
```

but it returns:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: So you want `id = [d['id'] for d in runs]`

Comment: what answer you expect, you want result in list or dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can help you.

```
id = []
for i in runs :
    id.append(i.get('id'))
```

> [12, 16]

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a list to a `json.load` function. Please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). `Load()` does not accep lists, it accepts

> a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a JSON document

Answer (score 0):

If you want your result in list of dictionary then:

```
result = [{x:y} for i in range(len(data)) for x,y in data[i].items() if x=='id' or x=='name' or x=='description']
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'name'}, {'id': 12}, {'description': 'desc.'}, {'name': 'namae)'}, {'id': 16}, {'description': 'desc1'}]
```

the `data` is your list of dictionary data.
hope this answer helpful for you.

Comment: this works aswell but going with the. Tejas's answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry. Forgot :). My code is so close to being done, but i have problem with my string that gets information.
it should be like
    ('get_tests/1/ ')
and i need to have a id[o] instead of the 1.
i have tried ('get_tests/' + id[o] + '/ ')
but it doens't work

Comment: i didn't get complete exactly what you want please mention properly or make changes in your question please.